# Gcc does not give any warning when converting from 64 bit to 32 bit

Tags: c++, gcc, casting

This is my code:

```
int main()
{
    uint64_t a = 100;
    uint32_t b = a;
    return 0;
}
```

Gcc command:

```
~$ gcc -o 1 1.c -Wall
~$
```

Can any one give me some help?

Comment: What if you add `-O2`? OTOH, the compiler may see that there's no loss of value, so, it's probably not a good example.

Comment: Why should it warn? The conversion from unsigned 64-bit to unsigned 32-bit is legal and has well defined behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried -Wall -Wconversion -Wextra. But it does not work. Can you give some details?

Comment: @btbsnc: Old version of GCC perhaps? v4.5.3 / Cygwin gives me the expected warning, v4.1.2 / Linux doesn't.

Comment: Yes, you are right! It's 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52), x86_64-redhat-linux. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned the version of gcc. Thank you all!

Comment: I changed the title to say "converting" instead of "casting". There are no casts in this code.

Answer (score 8):

Use -Wconversion option.

> -Wconversion
>     Warn for implicit conversions that may alter a value. This includes conversions between real and integer, like abs (x) when x is double; conversions between signed and unsigned, like unsigned ui = -1; and conversions to smaller types, like sqrtf (M_PI). Do not warn for explicit casts like abs ((int) x) and ui = (unsigned) -1, or if the value is not changed by the conversion like in abs (2.0). Warnings about conversions between signed and unsigned integers can be disabled by using -Wno-sign-conversion.
>
> For C++, also warn for confusing overload resolution for user-defined conversions; and conversions that never use a type conversion operator: conversions to void, the same type, a base class or a reference to them. Warnings about conversions between signed and unsigned integers are disabled by default in C++ unless -Wsign-conversion is explicitly enabled.

On your code:

conversion to «uint32_t {aka unsigned int}» from «uint64_t {aka long long unsigned int}» may alter its value [-Wconversion]

Answer (score 2):

It is a common misconception that `-Wall` turns on all warnings.

It turns on "*all the warnings about constructions that some users consider questionable, that are easy to avoid (or modify to prevent the warning), even in conjunction with macros*" (quoting the GCC manual).

Even `-Wextra` only "*enables some extra warning flags that are not enabled by -Wall*" (again from the GCC manual).

There is also `-pedantic`, which generates warnings in those cases where the meaning of the code is clear to the compiler, yet the standard demands a conforming compiler to issue a message. (GCC's default is to silently continue compiling).

**Even with all three enabled, you won't get every warning the compiler is capable of giving. Check the compiler manual for more details.**

Comment: Maybe you should also mention `-Wpedantic`?

Comment: -Wpedantic is invalid. I tried -pedantic but it does not work.

Comment: @btbsnc: Jeez, those are the reports I just love. What do you mean, "I tried `-pedantic` but it does not work"? Did you get an error message, and if yes, what was the message? Did the result not match your expectations? If yes, what was the observed result, and what was your expectation? Generally speaking, though, I'd recommend you **R**ead **T**he **F**ine **M**anual of the tools you are using...

Comment: I need some warning when casting from uint64_t to uint32_t but nothing   happened. So "it does not work".

Comment: @btbsnc: Neither leemes nor myself claimed it would. ForEveR already gave you the specific compiler option needed in your case. I added the more general advice that even `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` won't cover everything that a compiler could warn about, because I felt it topical in this case as you apparently worked under the assumption it would. **Please do read the manual on compiler warning options.**